# Unable to pip install --upgrade simplejson under cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, pip, simplejson

In Windows 10 and a 64bit Cygwin installed today with all python packages. I then installed pip using `python -m ensurepip`.

After that the `pip install --upgrade simplejson` goes awry like this

```
$ pip install --upgrade simplejson
Collecting simplejson
  Using cached simplejson-3.8.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: simplejson
  Found existing installation: simplejson 3.6.5
    Uninstalling simplejson-3.6.5:
      Successfully uninstalled simplejson-3.6.5
      1 [main] python2.7 7452 child_info_fork::abort: unable to map C:\cygwin64\lib\python2.7\site-packages\simplejson\_speedups.dll, Win32 error 126
    Error [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable while executing command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_nSo9B/simplejson/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-yReBDw-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
  Running setup.py install for simplejson ... error
  Rolling back uninstall of simplejson
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 880, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 678, in call_subprocess
    cwd=cwd, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1231, in _execute_ch
```

`simplejson` is already available through the CygWin installation, but the upgrade goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to install simplejson through the installer when you already installed it through pip. That can cause issues when done so.

I'd recommend seeking help if you don't know how to remove both, the pip version as well as the Cygwin version, manually.

OFF TOPIC: (I'm still wondering why there is no "pip3" on my Cygwin and that pip installed to the 2.7, even when ran under python3. Ruined my Cygwin setup, that has no backup recently either... *sigh* Got to purge Python stuff now...)